# UITabBarController only showing half of its UITabBar (off screen)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

My UITabBar is not completely showing after I present a UITabBarController from a UIViewController. Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

My code is:

```
//some method

LoggedInViewController *lvc = [[[LoggedInViewController alloc] initWithAccount:account] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    LoggedInFeedNavigationController *navController = [[LoggedInFeedNavigationController alloc] initWithAccount:self.account];
    [self.tabController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navController]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tabController.view];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Which part of the bar is not showing up? does it look like the whole view is moved off screen?

Comment: @Nicholas S yes, that is correct.

Comment: "When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller." source http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Was I meant to have a UINavigationController and then a UITabBarController inside that rather than how I am doing it (the other way round)?

Comment: @Howey-Ya-Doing No, the general practice is to have tabbar controller and to set navigation controllers to be it's bar contollers.

Comment: doesn't make sense, what do you mean by bar contollers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice to do:

```
[viewController1.view addSubview:viewController2.view];
```

The point of the MVC design is lost. The view controller should get your data (from the model) and put it in the view. If you have more than one view just arrange the functionality of the views to accept the corresponding data.

So if you need a tab bar controller you should do the following:

```
// assuming you are in the same initial controller
UITabBarController* pTabBarControllerL = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
MyFirstController* pFirstControllerL = [[MyFirstController alloc] init];
[pTabBarControllerL setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:pFirstControllerL]];
// perhaps set more tab bar controller properties - button images and so on
[self presentModalViewController:pTabBarControllerL animated:YES];
// release the memory you do not need

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // do your work in pFirstControllerL
}
```

PS: You should not subclass UINavigationController and UITabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

Actually according to the Apple's recommendations UITabBarViewController should be the root in the UIWindow hierarchy. We had hard times trying to put TabBar VCs or Navigation VCs not to the root.