# UITabBarController's TabBar is slightly hidden

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

My UITabBarController's tabBar is slightly off the view, please can you tell me what is wrong with my code:

```
LoggedInViewController *lvc = [[[LoggedInViewController alloc]
                               initWithAccount:account] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:lvc animated:YES];

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    LoggedInFeedNavigationController *navController;
    navController = [[LoggedInFeedNavigationController alloc]
                     initWithAccount:self.account];
    [self.tabController setViewControllers:
        [NSArray arrayWithObject:navController]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tabController.view];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Don ask the same thing twice: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6399054/760275

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the tabController view as a subview, but you have not specified where it should be located within its parent view, or how it should be resized when the parent view changes size. Try the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; // see note

    self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    LoggedInFeedNavigationController *navController;
    navController = [[LoggedInFeedNavigationController alloc]
                      initWithAccount:self.account];
    [self.tabController setViewControllers:
        [NSArray arrayWithObject:navController]];

    UIView *tabView = self.tabController.view;
    [self.view addSubview:tabView];

    tabView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    tabView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
}
```

Note: you are not [required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824695/do-i-always-have-to-call-super-viewdidload-in-the-viewdidload-method) to call `[super viewDidLoad]`, but if you *do* decide to call it, you should call it at the [beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844195/super-viewdidload-convention) of your `viewDidLoad` method, and not at the end.