# Why I Use Addsubview to add other controller's view,the view will move down 20point?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I am using the code below to test the problem.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [window setRootViewController:controller];
    UIViewController *controller2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [controller.view addSubview:controller2.view];
    controller2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    UIViewController *controller3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    controller3.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [controller2.view addSubview:controller3.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and when I run them on simulator or iphone,it will appear that
[image](http://img181.poco.cn/mypoco/myphoto/20110625/17/564008022011062517252907.jpg)
I'm very puzzled because this problem occur in my project,but when I used system's photo picker,it will appear right.
So,who can help me,thank you very much.

Comment: You should also have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399054/uitabbarcontroller-only-showing-half-of-its-uitabbar-off-screen/6399280#6399280).

Answer (score 1):

By default, `UIViewController`'s `view` uses the `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` value as its frame. This usually accounts for the status bar and is `(0, 20, 320, 460)`. So you find the view's pushing downwards as you add them hierarchically.